# Lotus Script Multi-thread Message Box

Tags: multithreading, lotus-domino

I have some code lifted from [IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21089495).

This creates an agent which is then run and it works.

In order to track what's going on I have inserted two message boxes.

The first:
`MessageBox view.Toplevelentrycount & " Encrypted Documents", MB_OK, view.Name`

The second is similar but contains different text.  The issue is that these message boxes block the execution of the agent.  I have researched this to find a page about threading in Lotus Script.

Which is  [How Synchronisation Works](http://webmail.dotd.louisiana.gov/help/help8_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/27150952fe7ac7388525731b00499e82?OpenDocument)

This is the closest which I have found to pushing my message box onto another thread but I am unable to achieve my goal.

Ideally, I'd like the whole agent to run in its own thread as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want threading, rewrite your agent in Java. LotusScript can't do that.

The other alternative would be to look into one of the various solutions people have come up with for showing a progress bar.  Here are two of them: [Karl-Henry's progress bar using Win32 APIs](http://blog.texasswede.com/progressbar-class-for-lotusscript/), [Erdun Eruc's progress bar using the print statement](http://www.keysolutions.com/notesfaq/howprogress.html)

On the other hand, there's also the Java route but without multi-threading - just using a progress bar there, too. It's a lot simpler than working with threads. Here's [Jake Howlett's Java Progress Bar for Notes agents](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20120330-0645).